# is there a way to get array indexed by table names in PHP MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using php with MySQL PDO, so my goal is to do a select from multiple tables at the same time, the problem is those tables contains some identical field names (like status, user_id, deleted etc).

So, is there a way to get the result in an array indexed by table names like in cakePHP:

```
//--SQL Query
$db->query('Select users.id, users.name, users.status, users.deleted, 
books.id, books.name, books.status, books.deleted where 
users.id=books.user_id AND user.id=1');

//--result I need
array (
  ['users']=>array(
    'id'=>1,
    ['name']=>'test',
    ['status']=>'active',
    ['deleted']=>0
  ),
  ['books']=>array(
    ['id']=>2,
    ['user_id']=>1,
    ['name']=>'Lost Word',
    ['status']=>'pending',
    ['deleted']=>0
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO doesn't have any feature to do this for you. You have to write code to process the rows returned by PDO.

But you'll have to know which column came from which table yourself. Even [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) doesn't return the origin table for each column, because sometimes an expression in the select-list doesn't correspond to any single table.

For example, how would you arrange the result for this query?

```
SELECT users.deleted + books.deleted AS `either_deleted`
FROM users JOIN books ON users.id=books.user_id
```